# Am I using these pointers correctly? I'm assigning something, but it's null immediately afterwards

Tags: c, pointers, null

```
if ((*l).proc == NULL)
    {
        (*l).proc = current_process;
        if(current_process == NULL)
        {
            __no_operation();
        }
        if((*l).proc == NULL)
        {
            __no_operation();
        }
    }
```

When running this code, I added breakpoints at both no-ops.  However, it only breaks at the second of the two.  How is this possible?

Comment: Could the no-ops have been optimised away by the compiler?

Comment: Just a style isseu, but why don't you do this? `if (!l->proc)` instead of `if ((*l).proc == NULL)`

Comment: Another thing, what is current_process and l->proc? Are they pointers? Integers? Structs?

Comment: I was doing the -> operator before, but I tried (*l).proc just to see if craziness was afoot.  current_process and l-> proc are both structs.

Answer (score 0):

Any sane compiler will have optimized these two identical blocks into a single block. It will probably also optimize the two conditionals into one. If you want to see both running separately, add `puts("A");` to the first and `puts("B");` to the second.

Comment: I changed it so the if(current_process == NULL) is outside the main if statement (and thus the first thing to run), which should avoid compiler optimization (I think).  It still breaks only at the second no-op.